# How to find broken mp3 files with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3

I have my personal mp3 collection which partially damaged after my HDD broken.
I need find names of damaged mp3s inside quite a lot (aprox. >5k files) in folders and sub-folders.

Can you please give me a tip about python 3 libraries which can open mp3 file, read it and find bit rate issues in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes ideally fits [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) here is [**solution**](https://m5-web.com/blog/165) with comments.
Everything is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

For the various steps, I can give you the following hints.

#### File names

For obtaining mp3 file names the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module is your friend: `glob.iglob('*.mp3', recursive=True)`.

#### Dealing with mp3

For dealing with mp3 files you can use practically any command line utility that serves your needs. A few examples:

- [avprobe](https://askubuntu.com/a/249843/445311)
- [exiftool, ffmpeg, mplayer](https://askubuntu.com/a/303461/445311)
- [mediainfo](https://superuser.com/a/595205/742396)

You can run these tools from within python via the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. For example:

```
subprocess.check_output(['avprobe', 'path/to/file'])
```

Then you can parse the output as appropriate; how to detect if the file is broken needs to be explored though.

#### Dive into mp3

If you're feeling adventurous then you can also scan the mp3 files directly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) gives a hint about the file structure. So in order to get the bit rate the following should do:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as fp:
    fp.read(2)  # Skip the first two bytes.
    bit_rate = fp.read(1) & 0xf0
```